# Consulta de N registros por Item

Tags: sql, select, query

Eu tenho uma tabela de históricos no `DB2` e gostaria de realizar um agrupamento por `PLACA` porem apesar disto eu teria que retornar os ultimo 5 registros de cada `PLACA`.

Ex.:

```
|ID |PLACA | DATA       | VALOR |
|12 |ABC   | 2014-08-28 | 4.50  |
|11 |DFG   | 2014-08-28 | 3.50  |
|10 |ABC   | 2014-08-27 | 2.50  |
|9  |DFG   | 2014-08-27 | 4.50  |
|8  |DFG   | 2014-08-26 | 3.50  |
|7  |ABC   | 2014-08-26 | 2.50  |
|6  |DFG   | 2014-08-25 | 4.50  |
|5  |DFG   | 2014-08-24 | 3.50  |
|4  |ABC   | 2014-08-24 | 2.50  |
|3  |DFG   | 2014-08-23 | 4.50  |
|2  |ABC   | 2014-08-23 | 4.50  |
|1  |ABC   | 2014-08-22 | 4.50  |
```

Deveria retornar:
Os registros de `ID` 12, 10, 7, 4 e 2 da `PLACA` ABC
e
Os registros de `ID` 11, 9, 8, 6 e 5 da `PLACA` DFG

Retorno esperado:

```
|ID |PLACA | DATA       | VALOR |
|12 |ABC   | 2014-08-28 | 4.50  |
|10 |ABC   | 2014-08-27 | 2.50  |
|7  |ABC   | 2014-08-26 | 2.50  |
|4  |ABC   | 2014-08-24 | 2.50  |
|2  |ABC   | 2014-08-23 | 4.50  |
|11 |DFG   | 2014-08-28 | 3.50  |
|9  |DFG   | 2014-08-27 | 4.50  |
|8  |DFG   | 2014-08-26 | 3.50  |
|6  |DFG   | 2014-08-25 | 4.50  |
|5  |DFG   | 2014-08-24 | 3.50  |
```

Comment: Qual formato de retorno você espera, Cristiano? IDs serializados (ex. | ABC | 12, 10, 7, 4, 2 |)? Recordsets individuais? Adicione à sua pergunta um exemplo do retorno desejado.

Comment: Qual banco de dados?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seguindo a resposta do @CristianoAvilaSalomão eu acho válido mostrar a ***SQL*** completa.

```
SELECT ID, PLACA, DATA, VALOR,ROWS FROM 
(
    SELECT ID, PLACA, DATA, VALOR, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PLACA ORDER BY DATA DESC) AS ROWS FROM PLACAS 
) AS PLACAS 
WHERE ROWS < 6
```

Answer (score 2):

Fiz um processo de ordenação decrescente pela data depois apliquei o seguinte comando:

`ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PLACA ORDER BY DATA DESC) AS ROWNUM`

Montei uma subquery e pedi para retornar apenas os itens onde `ROWNUM <= 5`